# Error in android development, gradle build failed

Tags: java, android, gradle, intellij-idea

So, ever since I updated my repository from my group, I got this error, however, when I looked at the commits all that changes in the built-in files are the version of gradle and jdk. I've searched and done possible solution regarding the app:processDebugMainMAnifest and I just don't know how I can resolve this problem.

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @645de77a

Comment: Inside your app folder, you have a build folder. Try deleting that and re-building your project.

Comment: @CalumTempleton I've tried this, however same error appears